# Add custom block in Magento 2 admin dashboard

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.1, dashboard, custom-block

Is there any way to add a custom block in magento 2 admin dashboard? I have a requirement to add custom table in dashboard. Can anyone help me?

[image]

My current magento version 2.2.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try to create a custom module that adds the a block there. Create:

**\app\code\Custom\Module\registration.php:**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Custom_Module',
__DIR__);
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\etc\module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.block" after="-" template="Custom_Module::custom.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**\app\code\Custom\Module\view\adminhtml\templates\custom.phtml:**

```
<?php
    echo 'custom code here';
```

Don't forget to run:

**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Comment: This worked, but instead I used <referenceContainer name="header"> to insert custom block into the admin header area