# Magento 2 : Can not add custom block in admin panel dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin, dashboard

I want to add a **custom block** to Magento 2 admin panel dashboard.

I have tried the following [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217150/add-custom-block-in-magento-2-admin-dashboard) but it's not working.

I am using `Magento 2.1.7`

Comment: [This](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Custom-Block-in-admin-Order-view-of-Magento-2/td-p/70787) will help you to achieve, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have tried it but not working. I can not get my custom block to dashboard with all other blocks (i.e. Last Search Terms, Top Search Terms etc.) Please refer another solution.